# How to request focus on TextInputLayout programmatically in case of error?

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

i have five fields in a form and on validation error message and floating labels are working perfectly but in the case of error when I am calling `requestFocus()` method on a particular `TextInputLayout` object then it is not getting focussed.

Code Snippet:

```
                BetterSpinner Spinner_material = (BetterSpinner)rfqItem.findViewById(R.id.Spinner_material);
            if(Spinner_material.getText()!=null && Spinner_material.getText().toString().length()>0)
            {
                TextInputLayout_category.setError(null);
                TextInputLayout_category.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                if(isReporting)
                {
                    TextInputLayout_category.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    TextInputLayout_category.setError(baseActivity.getString(R.string.addrfq_validationerror_material_category));
                    TextInputLayout_category.requestFocus();
                }
                flag=false;
            }
```

XML Snippet :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.power2sme.android.utilities.customviews.BetterSpinner
                android:id="@+id/Spinner_material"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/addrfq_hint_sku_category"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

BetterSpinner is a third party library and it is derived from AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: post your xml and code please =)

Answer (score 0):

i will give one example that are running here in my application.

```
private boolean validatePassword() {
        if (inputPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
            inputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
            requestFocus(inputPassword);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
            inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }


private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

### **EDIT**

Add my requestFocus method to your code and try below code:

```
BetterSpinner Spinner_material = (BetterSpinner)rfqItem.findViewById(R.id.Spinner_material);
            if(Spinner_material.getText()!=null && Spinner_material.getText().toString().length()>0)
            {
                TextInputLayout_category.setError(null);
                TextInputLayout_category.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                if(isReporting)
                {
                    TextInputLayout_category.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    TextInputLayout_category.setError(baseActivity.getString(R.string.addrfq_validationerror_material_category));
                    requestFocus(Spinner_material);
                }
                flag=false;
            }
```

Comment: thankx for your quick answer but In my case there is AutoCompleteTextView inside TextInputLayout and it is showing problem in focus

Comment: Try to requestFocus(Spinner_material);
using my code requestFocus

Comment: what happens when you requestFocus to the Spinner? its just doesnt focus?

Comment: Ok, i will implement a form using the Spinner you have used, and send you a msg if a found a solution. If you find one, please msg me =)

Answer (score 0):

When requesting focus for a view:

```
private void requestFocus(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        yourcoordinatorlayout.clearFocus();
        view.requestFocus();
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

When clearing all focus in `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
private void clearFocusFromAll() {
    yourcoordinatorlayout.clearFocus();
}
```

In you `Activity` declare `CoordinatorLayout` like :

```
CoordinatorLayout yourcoordinatorlayout=(CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.registerCoordinatorLayout);
```

And xml will be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/registerCoordinatorLayout"
tools:context=".activity.RegisterActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme3.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme3.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- your views will be here, you can add nestedscrollview,layouts etc. -->
<include layout="@layout/content_register" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```